# jquery show fancy box on page load

Tags: jquery, .net

I would like to launch a Fancybox  on page load. I could bind it to a hidden anchor tag and fire the click event of that anchor tag via JavaScript.bt ineed to open it only on certain condition is true.How can i do trhat?

Answer (score 0):

Call it on the document ready. You can check your conditions and then invoke

```
var yourConditionVariableVal =false;
$(function(){
  if(yourConditionVariableVal)
  {
     $("#yourImage").fancybox();
  }
});
```

The above code will bind the fancy box to an element with id yourImage.

If you want to show the fancybox on page load event, you can trigger it.

```
var yourConditionVariableVal =false;
$(function(){
  if(yourConditionVariableVal)
  {
     $("#yourImage").fancybox();
     $("#yourImage").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    if(condition) {
        $.fancybox({
            // fancybox options
        });
    }
});
```